# What is Ayatollah Khamenei's ruling regarding men wearing short trousers in front of women (in streets or parties)?

Tags: shiism, men, clothing

Occasionally I see some boys or men who wear shorts (short trousers) in the streets or other public places. (Or even in the parties). On the other hand, According to Resalah-al-Amaliah ([www.bahjat.ir](http://www.bahjat.ir/index.php/ahkam/resaleh/283-2011-09-07-02-31-30.html)) it is Haram for women to look at the body of non-Mahram men. (Ehtiat-Wajib)

What could be the ruling of it in the case that there are non-Mahrams at that place? (If it stimulates them…)

**Note:** I am looking for the viewpoint of Ayatollah Khamenei (as a scholar of Shia and likewise a Marja'ul Taqlid of Shia)

Comment: "the ruling"?  According to who?  There's countless scholars out there who can make rulings.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I agree with you. I added some related text to it. Actually I specified it to the view of Shia scholars (contemporary scholars).

Comment: @goldPseudo, you mentioned there's countless scholars ..., alright, I made it limited it solely according to the ruling of Ayatollah Khamenei as a Marja'al Taqlid of Shia (and also as a scholar of Shia).

Comment: This is a site for Islam. Any answer from the Islamic sources (Qur'an, hadith etc.) should be encouraged.

Comment: If the answers below satisfy your query please mark the relevant one as accepted. Else please elaborate on your doubts/questions.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer the question I can mention a related inquiry. Someone inquired a similar question that asked "what is the ruling of wearing shorts (Short trousers) for men in public places?" 
Answer: (seemingly this is the Fatwa of Ayatollah Khamenei about this)

> If men know that non_Mahram women would look at them whenever their
>   bodies are naked, so according to Ihtiat-al-Wajib (mandatory caution)
>   they ought to cover those parts except head, neck, and hands.

---

**Reference:**

- [talabehpasokhgoo.parsiblog.com](http://talabehpasokhgoo.parsiblog.com/Posts/847/$PBADVLINK$?P=11)

Answer (score 0):

With due respect to your request for an answer with Shia point of view, I wanted to also point out in Islam that the awrah for men is what is between the navel and knees. So the portion between the belly button and the knees needs to be covered in front of BOTH non-mahram men and women.

*And modesty is an integral part of faith for both genders. :)*